# Rails: Hooking into ORM generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, generator

I'd like to run a generator from a gem whenever a model generator is invoked.

The following

```
require 'rails'

module Mygenerator
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie

    config.app_generators.orm :my_generator

  end
end
```

properly invokes my generator but Rails' native generator aren't run anymore.

I assume that I could run the native generator via `invoke`, but that seems overly complex. And how about all the other generators of the ORM?

Is there a better way to "attach" my generator to an existing one?

---

**Update:**

This naturally works — but I'm still hoping for something cleaner:

```
module Rails
  module Generators
    class ModelGenerator < NamedBase

      def run_my_custom_generator
        invoke "my_generator:foo"
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
require 'rails'

class Rails::Generators::ModelGenerator
  include Mygenerator::full_namespace_here::class
  extend  Mygenerator::full_namespace_here::ClassMethods
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion — I’ll see if this would work in my context.